# How to control returning value / table of a stored procedure

Tags: sql

```
ALTER PROC SP_SampleInner
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TB_Whatever
```

Other procedure

```
ALTER RPROC SP_SampleOuter
AS
DECLARE @count int
EXEC @count = SP_SampleInner

IF @count > 0
BEGIN
SELECT 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 0
END
```

What I want is SP_SampleOuter returns more than one table because of EXEC SP_SampleInner (I think). How could I control returning tables/values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
ALTER PROC SP_SampleOuter
AS
DECLARE @count int
EXEC @count = SP_SampleInner

IF @count > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @count as Ctr,1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @count as Ctr,0
END
```

Simply add the count variable as the first field you return

Answer (score 0):

Use an output variable to send the count back.

Comment: Could you explain how do I do it?

Comment: I think  HLGEM meant `ALTER PROCEDURE SP_SampleOuter (@Count INT OUTPUT)`

Comment: Actually I meant for him to look it up in Books online once he knew what ti was called.